# Amortized analysis of Integer set ADT (Java exam)

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

If I'm not misunderstanding amortized analysis, then this exam question is really sneaky. So I guess I'm misunderstanding.

"Implement a Set ADT with capacity n, that can contain all positive integers less than or equal to n. Requirements:

new Set(n) - O(n)

insert(i) - O(1)

member(i) - O(1)

union(s) - O(1), where s is a Set of the same type. You may destroy s if you like.

Do a running time analysis of the operations. Use amortized analysis if you want."

You can implement this as a boolean array of size n. Easy peasy. The only hard bit is the union operation. I couldn't figure it out and the solution suggested a for loop doing 'size(s)' AND operations, which is obviously O(n). But after the for loop, they set the boolean array of s to null, and claimed this made the amortized running time O(1)!

Sure, if you keep unioning your new set with the same set s, n times, you've got an average running time of O(1) since only one of the operations are O(n) and the rest are constant. But why would we care about that? How do you justify this analysis? How is doing a pointless operation n times a fair benchmark for amortized analysis?

Comment: You're right, that claim seems fishy. The case that n union operations with n distinct sets are performed needs to be considered, and should have complexity Θ(n) even under amortized analysis. Are you sure that's all they do?

Comment: Perhaps you amortize in the cost of building the set.  Maybe union costs the size of the smaller set, and each element gets added with constant cost. So, if you do a union with a large number of elements, you first had to add each of those elements individually (many low cost operations) first.  Not certain of this--just a first impression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's ignore insert(i) and member(i) queries for the time being, and focus just on creating new sets and forming unions.

The trick is that if you destroy s after performing union(s), then in any sequence of new set creations and union operations, **it's never possible to perform more unions than set creations**: every union operation requires at least 2 sets to be currently in existence, and reduces the total number of sets in existence by 1.

Consider any sequence of c new set creations and u < c union operations: this will take O(nc+nu+c+u) = O(nc+nu) time.  (Set creation is allowed to be O(n), and this is also the time for a straightforward union computation.)  The fact that we know that u < c means that we can devise a new cost system in which, for *any* such sequence, we can match each union operation up with a distinct set creation that happened earlier, and *charge* the time for the union to its matching set creation.  In this new cost system, all union operations take time O(1), all set creations that are matched with a later union operation take time O(n+1)+O(n+1) = O(n), and unmatched set creations take time O(n+1) = O(n) as before.  Notice that although individual costs have moved around, the *total* cost under this new system is the same as in the original: O(2nu+n(c-u)+c+u) = O(nc+nu).

So if assume pessimistically that *every* set creation will be charged to some future union operation, so that the cost of every set creation becomes (or rather, remains) O(n+1)+O(n+1) = O(n), and the cost of every union operation becomes O(1), this even newer cost will be an upper bound on (i.e. will never underestimate) the new cost system, which is the true cost of any sequence of set creations and union operations.

Comment: Fantastic explanation, but I still really find it to be such a sneaky trick question... If we arbitrarily destroy the other set, it's O(1) amortized but if we don't, it's O(n)?? We've added a line of computation that doesn't even affect the object that is being operated upon, and that IMPROVES running time? If that's not rules lawyering, I don't know what is...

Comment: It's tricky :)  But there are sometimes situations where this would be all you need, much as there are situations where it's OK to add a number to a total without keeping the previous total around.  And BTW, if you thought it was helpful, I'd appreciate an upvote ;)